# I'm having an error when running multiple promises using Promise.All

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I have a string of promises, but it is not being executed.

This is the sequence, and it is working, but I have to use Promise.all.

```
 dataObj[0].pushScreen.map(item => {
      console.log(item.page);

      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(username)
        .child(item.nameComponent)
        .putFile(item.page)
        .then(() => console.log('Imagem enviada'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Imagem não enviada: ' + err));
    });
```

I tried to do it that way, but it didn't work

```
 Promise.all(() => {
    dataObj[0].pushScreen.map(item => {
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(username)
        .child(item.nameComponent)
        .putFile(item.pages)
        .then(() => console.log('Imagem enviada'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Imagem não enviada: ' + err));
    });
  })
    .then(function(values) {
      console.log('Resolvidas');
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('erro'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either remove the function block or return your promise.

```
Promise.all(
    dataObj[0].pushScreen.map((item) =>
        firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(username)
            .child(item.nameComponent)
            .putFile(item.pages)
            .then(() => console.log('Imagem enviada'))
            .catch((err) => console.log('Imagem não enviada: ' + err))
    )
)
    .then(function(values) {
        console.log('Resolvidas');
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('erro'));
```